# Fill background-color with 2 colors height-wise

Tags: css, background-color

I'm looking for a way to set the background-color of an HTML document with 2 colors instead of one. This kind of question has been asked before, but I want to set the two colors *height-wise* (split vertically) rather than width-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you found, but you can use `linear-gradient` for this:

```css
body {
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(204,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 50%); 
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

You just need to set the angle to `0 deg`

Answer (score 0):

You can define css like

```
#grad1 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange, white, green);
}
```

and use this css in your div

```
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Note: change color code and height as per your need

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply like this.

```
<div>
        <div className='first'>
          hello
        </div>
        <div className='second'>
          hi
        </div>
      </div>
```

Css:

```
.first{
  height: calc(50vh);
  background: blue;
}
.second{
  height: calc(50vh);
    background: red;
}
```